# Fraction Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Im not sure how to tackle this exactly would i use quotient rule?

$$-\frac{12}{s^5}$$

Kinda lost at this one maybe someone can quide me in the right path

Comment: If you can show your attempt at the quotient rule and explain the problem you're having using it, then we could show you what you're missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many options. One is to rewrite as $-12s^{-5}$.

Comment: Oh so just by moving the fraction up there turning it into a $s^-5?$ right

Comment: $1/(a^b)$ is the same thing as $a^{-b}$. Note that I haven't taken the derivative --- I've just rewritten the function in a way that might make it easy to take the derivative (without needing to use the quotient rule).

Comment: Okay i got it! !

Comment: Now that you've gotten it, you should try actually using the quotient rule, which says that the derivative of $f/g$ is $(g\cdot f'-f\cdot g')/g^2$. The wonderful thing about these rules is that the two different methods give the same result.